# Data validation doesn't work if contents is added by pasting using JAVA and Apache Poi

Tags: java, excel, validation, apache-poi

I am creating an Excel sheet using Java code. I am able to generate the sheet, but now i have to add data validation also for particular columns. Here is my code:

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Data Validation");

    // set style to the cell
    CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();        
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
    style.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    Row row = sheet.createRow((short) 0);

    // Create a cell and put a value in it.
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("First Name");
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue("Last Name");
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
    cell = row.createCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue("Age");
    cell.setCellStyle(style);


    //CellRangeAddressList(index_of_starting_row, index_of_ending_row, index_of_starting_column,index_of_ending_column);
    CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1, 90, 2, 2);
    DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint(new String[]{"10", "20", "30"});
    DataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList, dvConstraint);
    dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
    sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);

    // show error
    dataValidation.setErrorStyle(DataValidation.ErrorStyle.STOP);
    dataValidation.createErrorBox("Box Title", "Message Text");
    String file = "test.xls";
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```

The data validation is working when i type the number other than 10,20,30. But if i paste some other number in the column then the validation is surpassed. What can be the solution for this?

I am using Apache poi library.

Answer (score 1):

[Data Validation](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-c743a24a-bc48-41f1-bd92-95b6aeeb73c9) can be superceded by any programming that assigns a value to the cell. This is not restricted to [tag:apache:poi]. Even the VBE's **Immediate** window can bypass Data Validation restrictions with something like,

```
activecell = 99
```

... where the [ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) holds simple data validation like the following.

[image: data_validation_bypass]

Comment: so what could be the solution for this?

Comment: Duplicate (or recover/read into code) the conditions of the Data Validation and test your own values before transferring them. Possibly switch native Data Validation for a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro.